# Use uib-typeahead to loop through an object

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm trying to use uib-typeahead to loop through an object but I can't figure out what to put in the `uib-typeahead` argument.

My HTML is:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="option for option in options" class="form-control">
```

And my Angular code is:

```
$scope.options = {
    22: "Abc",
    27: "Def",
    55: "Ghi"
}
```

If I type anything right now I don't see anything. I would like to get the key value in the input when I selected one of the options. What should I put in the `uib-typeahead` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an object to populate the dropdown instead of an array. Here's a plunker showing it working correctly with an array http://plnkr.co/edit/8VkpF4pKHBMKrPQPtnkT?p=preview

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
function TypeaheadCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.options = [
    "Abc",
    "Def",
    "Ghi"
  ];
}
```

You can transform the object into an array like this

```
var obj = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'};

var arr1 = [];
for (var i in obj) {
  arr1.push(obj[i]);
}
// or you can use lodash https://lodash.com/
var arr2 = _.map(obj);
//both result in ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: I'm getting back the object from an API. I'll figure out if I can transform te object to an array in the API.